# Xpath query 'like' substitution

Tags: python, xpath

Okay, so I've got some example xml that looks like this:

```
<Node name="details">
   <Node name="1130482269">
      <Val name="type"><u>2</u></Val>
      <Val name="owner"><n/></Val>
      <Val name="account_number"><u>99-71-39</u></Val>
   </Node>
   <Node name="570722270">
      <Val name="type"><u>2</u></Val>
      <Val name="owner"><n/></Val>
      <Val name="account_number"><u>99 71 40</u></Val>
   </Node>
   <Node name="1845243341">
      <Val name="type"><u>2</u></Val>
      <Val name="owner"><n/></Val>
      <Val name="account_number"><u>9971-41</u></Val>
   </Node>
</Node>
```

I'm trying to do a search based on account_number. But there are so many different formats that it could be in. Some have spaces, some have dashes, some have a mixture etc. If I was able to do a search removing spaces and dashes, I should be able to get any account number.

With accountnumber being the search query, the ultimate goal is to get the second level node name number by doing a search in XPATH doing this:

```
doc = libxml2.parseDoc(xml)
ctxt = doc.xpathNewContext()
res = ctxt.xpathEval("/Node/Node[Val[@name='account_number']/*='" + str(accountnumber) + "']/@name")
```

Is there a way to use XPATH search, to remove all dashes and spaces, and leave only numbers?

Thanks

Comment: Cant you replace all ' ' and '-' with nothing? removing them from your text? Im not familiar with Python but as far as I know there is no way to do what you want with xpath only

Comment: maybe i could do a massive if statement :-(

Comment: You can probably create a regex to replace any '-' or ' ' that is between the <Val name="account_number"></Val> Tags or Query all Val[@account_number] nodes with xpath and rewrite their value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using `translate()`  function. Example:

```
"translate(Node/Node[@name='1130482269']/Val[@name='account_number'],'- ','')"
```

will output `997139`.

You can use then (code line broken for readability):

```
"translate(
  /Node/Node[@name='" + 
  str(accountnumber) + 
  "']/Val[@name='account_number'],'- ','')"
```

Note the white space included in the second argument of translate `'- '` (or even `'-&#x20;'`) necessary to remove white spaces.

Comment: And if you need a custom function to normalize your data instead of translate, you can craft your own extension function: http://lxml.de/extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the libxml2 environment only supports XPath 1.0, so you haven't got access to the regular expression capabilities of XPath 2.0, such as the matches() function. It does however have support for adding your own extension functions (see http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/extensions.html) so you could consider doing this yourself.